# how do I add statemine to local parachain setup? where do I find the statemine repo?

Tags: substrate-node-template, polkadot

I am running a local parachain setup.
how do I add statemine to the network ? is there a github registry for statemine with instructions? basically I would like to setup a local relaychain with assets on statemine

Answer (score 0):

All the `state*` parachains can be found in the cumulus repository.

Here is the specific link you are looking for: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/f0f13e09ddd203b8d29eb2f10123230557ce2da3/polkadot-parachain/src/chain_spec/asset_hubs.rs#L259

Recently, the structs have been renamed to `asset-hub*`. However, if you check the runtime files, they are still referred to as `state*` at present. You can find them here: https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/f0f13e09ddd203b8d29eb2f10123230557ce2da3/parachains/runtimes/assets/asset-hub-kusama/src/lib.rs#L103